# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'

Tags: python, utf-8

I have the following line of code where am I trying to decode to utf-8,how do I run this for a list?

```
radars_string = '\n'.join(changed_project_data['rdars'].decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Error:-

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Comment: presumably `changed_project_data` is a dictionary that stores lists against keys, so you'll need to `map` the decoding to the list contents rather than trying to call `.decode()` on the list itself. But you haven't shown the input structure so we can't say anything definitively; there's no way of knowing how nested your structure is and what can, and cannot, be decoded.

Answer (score 1):

You can decode individual strings in a list with a generator expression:

```
radars_string = '\n'.join(s.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') for s in changed_project_data['rdars'])
```

Comment: What if it's a heavily nested JSON response that the OP is working with, or similar? There's nothing to suggest that the OP is unaware that you can't just bulk-decode some list.

Comment: The OP states that he only needs help in handling a list of strings. To handle nested data structure, you can use a recursive function.

Comment: Yep, but the OP also doesn't understand "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'decode'" so it's a hit-and-hope that this will actually work.

Comment: I tried above but it gives me error `File "autosubmit.py", line 914, in <genexpr>
    radars_string = '\n'.join(s.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') for s in changed_project_data['rdars'])
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2602' in position 34: ordinal not in range(128)` ,my understanding is it's encountering a unicode character (specifically ☂) which has no ASCII equivalent

Comment: but we can get around this behaviour by using the `ignore` which am already using....why would I hit it with `string.decode('UTF-8', 'ignore')`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply `decode` to list.

You can use generator like this `'\n'.join([i.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') for i in changed_project_data['rdars']])` to apply decode to each element.

Or use map: `'\n'.join(map(lambda x: x.decode('utf8', 'ignore'), changed_project_data['rdars']))`.

Comment: What if it's a heavily nested JSON response that the OP is working with, or similar?

Comment: Author says, that it is a list, so I gave answer considering this condition.

Comment: And I'm asking if that list might contain dictionaries, or be a nested list, in which case you're just kicking the error further down the path. Stating that they have a "list" says _nothing_ about the contents of that list when the OP had the initial expectation that they could call `decode` on the list in the first place.

Comment: Ok, we can add condition to our generator or lambda function, like `'\n'.join([i.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') for i in changed_project_data['rdars'] if isinstance(i, str)])`

Comment: Or... just wait for proper clarification from the OP on the actual structure :)

Comment: Indeed, better to get answer from OP :)

Answer (score -2):

```
radars_string = '\n'.join([i.decode('utf-8', 'ignore') for i in changed_project_data['rdars']])
```

Comment: What if it's a heavily nested JSON response that the OP is working with, or similar? And this is identical to an existing answer.

Comment: @roganjosh If so, you need to write `for` loops. The syntax is `Str.decode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')`, which means the inner most loop should deal with a pure string.

Comment: It's not me that needs to know how to do this; my point is that I had a feeling people would pile in on answers without waiting for the OP to actually clarify the structure. I also appreciate for you that a) you cannot yet comment for clarification and b) it's a good shot to try get your foot on the ladder. Just be wary of the trap questions :)